# Cant get the desired star pattern. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python

Desired output:

```
       *
      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
```

Actual output:

```
       *      ***
     *****
    *******
   *********
  ***********
 *************
```

```
rows = int(input("ENTER NUMBER OF ROWS: "))
x = 0
count = 0
z =0
for i in range (rows, 0 , -1):
    print(" "*i , end ="")
    x += 1
    print("*" * x, end ="")
    count += 1
    if count>1:
        z += 1
        print("*" * z)
```

Comment: Actually, there are too many variables. you can do like `print(" "*x + "*" * y + " "* z)`. x + y+ z = constant and x= z. y can be easily calculated.

Comment: @drops the three starts in the actual output are on the same line as the single star. They should not be so.

Comment: Just for fun. After getting `rows` from the user it's just a one-liner: `print('\n'.join(' ' * (rows - row) + '* ' * row * 2 + '*' for row in range(rows)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't printing newline on after the first line because your count is exactly one. You can just put an else clause to fix that.

```py
rows = int(input("ENTER NUMBER OF ROWS: "))
x = 0
count = 0
z =0
for i in range (rows, 0 , -1):
    print(" "*i , end ="")
    x += 1
    print("*" * x, end ="")
    count += 1
    if count>1:
        z += 1
        print("*" * z)
    else:
        print("")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing a new line after first iteration. Code should be like below.

```
rows = int(7)
x = 0
count = 0
z = 0
for i in range(rows, 0, -1):
    print(" " * i, end="")
    x += 1
    print("*" * x, end="")
    count += 1
    if count > 1:
        z += 1
        print("*" * z)
    else:
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

`if count>1:` for 1st row is false, so you should check `count>0`. But it's always true, you can omit it. Also here is my suggestion how use and change `x` and `z`:

```
rows = int(input("ENTER NUMBER OF ROWS: "))
x = 1
z = 0
for i in range (rows, 0 , -1):
    print(" "*i, end ="")
    print("*"*x, end ="")
    print("*"*z)
    x += 1
    z += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This should work

rows = int(input("ENTER NUMBER OF ROWS: "))
x = 0
count = 0
z =0
for i in range (rows, 0 , -1):
    print(" "*i , end ="")
    x += 1
    print("*" * x, end ="")
    count += 1
    if count>1:
        z += 1
        print("*" * z)
    else:
        print()
```